# pass variable to iframe launch in fancybox

Tags: forms, variables, iframe, fancybox

I'm using fancybox to open an iframe that contains a submission form.

The form is fairly generic (name, email, comments) however I need to pass the form a dynamic variable.

How can I pass a variable from the parent page to my form in a fancybox iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wow guess I had a moment there.

I can just pass the variable in the url and use the $_GET function. on my form page.

```
<a id="request" href="http://www.url.com/requestform.php?var=var1">
```